# Can I use my homepage for the 404 page with a conditional pop up div?

Tags: jquery, http-status-code-404

I just did the following in htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.website.com
```

My first question is, it is OK for me to do this?

If there are any SEO/etc., etc. problems with redirecting 404's to 
the homepage let me know.

**Second question:**

The thing is I have a one-page site and I'd like to keep it that way.

What I would like to do is have a popup `div` show up, as an alternative to a 404 page.

So basically 404's get redirected to the homepage, where a popup then fades in with whatever 404 message in it.

How could I trigger the popup? The jquery code would somehow have to know that the user ended up here due to a 404. Is this even doable?

(I can manage the popup itself, but how to tell it to show up after
a 404 happens.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a query string to the URL that you're using as the 404 page.

#### .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.website.com?page=fourOhFour
```

Then, check to see if the variable is set to the proper value and if it is, create a variable in javascript.

#### Javascript/PHP

```
<script>
  is404 = "<?php echo $_GET['page'] ?>";
  if (is404 === "fourOhFour"){
    // jQuery popup code here
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To extend [Chris Herbert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944632/887539).

Using only JS:

```
<script>
  var is404 = location.href.search(/(\?|&)page=fourOhFour(\&|$)/g) =! -1;
  if ( is404 ) {
      // jQuery popup code here
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, much obliged.

I ended up doing this slightly differently. I'll post it here for the sake of usefulness.

HTACCESS:

```
 ErrorDocument 404 http://www.website.com/#404-not-found
```

JQUERY:

```
 if (window.location.hash == '#404-not-found') {
 setTimeout(function () { 
 $("#pageNotFound").slideDown(2222, 'easeOutBounce'); 
 }, 2888);  //delay
 }
```

So now a nice div slides down whenever there's a 404 error.